# Grouping SSAS measures

Tags: ssas, grouping, measures

Hi I have a fact table in my cube with member visits to a building. There is an hour dimension on the fact table. For example:

Member 1 visits 2 times between 1:00-2:00 
Member 2 visits 2 times between 2:00-3:00 
Member 1 visits 2 times between 4:00-5:00

So overall 6 individual visits. Is there a way of getting unique visitors between 1:00 - 4:00 which in this case is 2.

It's a bit of vague question but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use distinct count in the measure aggregation

[Semi additive measures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175356.aspx)